# Chrome screen keyboard blocking content at bottom of page on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, responsive, mobile-website

Here, I recorded video about problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZbKix3XGTE

Problem is when keyboard on screen. The content is behind of keyboard not reachable. If there is input end of page user can't see what is typing in it.

I have this issue only with chrome, other browsers work normal.

All solutions in my mind about this contains javascript. But I am not sure javascript handle this perfectly. I wanted to ask you knowledge before start. Is there any other option for this only with CSS or something else?

Code in example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=1" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #top {
        background-color: lightgreen;
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
    }
    #bottom {
        background-color: green;
        height: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    #bottom > input {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="top">Top</div>
    <div id="bottom">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Codepen Link
https://codepen.io/hllktlhndd/pen/yZKzyZ

Answer (score 0):

Did you get answer for this ?
This worked before okay, but now the android-chrome comes on top of the page and does not push it up anymore.
I'm using webview, maybe they have some option for it?

Quick fix is to add padding at the bottom of the screen, maybe 200 - 300px